# How Lucene IndexReader on multi threading environment?

Tags: multithreading, solr, elasticsearch, lucene

Provided I want to read from the same IndexReader instance,presumably a singleton instance,from multiple threads how that would affect to the performance?Will there be "read lock" or anything that could potentially harm the possibility of multi threading?

Is there any best practise to use same IndexReader in multi threading environment?

Comment: As far as I know index reader is thread safe, it will create LOCK only if you have multiple index writers at same time. Possible duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878448/lucene-good-practice-and-thread-safety

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html),

```
IndexReader instances are completely thread safe, meaning multiple threads can call any 
of its methods, concurrently. If your application requires external synchronization,
you should not synchronize on the IndexReader instance; use your own (non-Lucene)
objects instead.
```

But another thing you would like to consider is , if the indexreader is shared by multiple threads and in that process the index gets updated, the updated index wont get reflected until you create a new indexreader instance.

Comment: I would also add that there is not a single lock involved at search time. This is possible thanks to the way that the index is stored, in write-once (immutable) generational files.