# Worker threads cause Lucene LockObtainFailedException

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, lucene

So I have been trying to implement [Lucene for App-Engine](https://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine/) as a superior replacement for the [GAE Search Api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/). My content is user generated; which means I will be adding content to the index dynamically at production time. Consequently my implementation for adding Documents to my index uses a Task Queue, that way my system can scale without problems. But I have encounter a problem where multiple worker threads trying to access the index cause LockObtainFailedException. Any ideas how I might resolve this? The LuceneFoAppEngine project linked above does contain the quote

> For high performance applications use google app engine task queue

So how might I do that while avoiding LockObtainFailedException? Is my only hope to create multiple indices and then when it's time to search, search all of them? (One dedicated index for each worker thread?)

Comment: You must reuse a single `IndexWriter` instance, rather than opening new ones.  It's designed to be reused, and is entirely thread safe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878448/lucene-good-practice-and-thread-safety

Comment: There seems to be some contradiction. The project says I can use Task Queue, and yet per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585365/behavior-of-singletons-in-task-queues-on-app-engine/30589631#30589631 I can't really have a single instance of IndexWriter with Task Queues because app-engine does not support single instance contracts. In the linked post, you can replace with `MySingletonIndexWriterWrapper` as in `IndexWriter writer = MySingletonIndexWriterWrapper.getIndexWriterSingleInstance();`

Comment: I have updated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585365/behavior-of-singletons-in-task-queues-on-app-engine for complete actual use case