# Behavior of singletons in task queues on app-engine

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, singleton, task-queue

What happens to my static variables when app-engine spins new instances? More specifically I am using a Task Queue that can have 40 instances/thread. Within the Servlet in question, I am using a singleton, as in

```
public class WorkerThread  extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      ..
      MySingleton single = MySingleton.getInstance();
      ..
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is how the singleton is created

```
public class MySingleton {

  public static I  MySingleton getInstance() {
    return   MySingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private static class MySingletonHolder {
    public static final MySingleton INSTANCE = new MySingleton();
  }

  private   MySingleton() {

  }
  ..
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Since this is a Task Queue, do I have to worry about App-Engine starting new instances to scale with high demands?
2. Does it matter if the singleton is an inner class of the WorkerThread class or another class that the WorkerThread class is accessing?
3. Are Task Queues instance independent? A believe they are but am not sure.

I hope the question is clear. I want there to be only one instance of my singleton across all instances. Please ask for clarification if the question is not clear.

**UPDATE**

Following is my exact use case

```
public class SingletonProductIndexWriter {

  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SingletonProductIndexWriter.class.getName());

  public static IndexWriter getSingleIndexWriter() {
    return IndexWriterHolder.INDEX_WRITER;
  }

  private static class IndexWriterHolder {

    static PorterAnalyzer analyzer = new PorterAnalyzer();
    static GaeDirectory index = new GaeDirectory(LuceneWorker.PRODUCTS);// create product index
    static IndexWriterConfig config = GaeLuceneUtil.getIndexWriterConfig(LuceneWorker.LUCENE_VERSION, analyzer);
    public static final IndexWriter INDEX_WRITER =  getIndexWriter();


    private static IndexWriter getIndexWriter() {
      try {
        LOG.info("Create single index writer for workers");
        return new IndexWriter(index, config);
      }catch(IOException e){
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

called as

```
IndexWriter writer = SingletonProductIndexWriter.getSingleIndexWriter();
```

For pertinent details see Stack Overflow thread: [Worker threads cause Lucene LockObtainFailedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577948/worker-threads-cause-lucene-lockobtainfailedexception)

Answer (score 2):

Push and Pull queues are both processed by standard instances (you can target a module/frontend/backend in your queue.xml). Instances will scale up to meet the needs of both your normal traffic as well as your queues.

Singletons (in the classic sense portrayed here) are only unique to the classloader they are loaded by - they definitely are not unique across instances of your application on appengine - no state will be shared. Using this pattern you will have one singleton per appengine instance.

If you need to share state, you will need to use the datastore/cloud sql/something.

Comment: I am using Lucene for search. And I use a Task Queue to write to the index. Lucene requires a single IndexWriter, which itself takes care of concurrent callers (as I understand it). The project I am using is https://code.google.com/p/lucene-appengine/ which claims that I can use Task Queue to scale. So how do I scale in a situation like this?

Comment: I have appended an update to the post for greater use case detail.

Comment: I haven't used lucene on appengine - if I were you I'd consider the full text search api (which is limited in capability) or move to lucene or elastic search on GCE. In an auto scaling environment such a limitation is probably unreasonable. Having said that, the best way to have a single write point is probably to use pull queues, triggered by a cron job. You can then pull a few hundred tasks at once and write them together. You can then use cron and queue rates to ensure only one batch is processed at a time. This won't guarantee they all run on the same instance though.