# Can I use a single Lucene Analyzer instance for the whole search application?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using the latest Lucene version 5.4.

I'm curious to know if an Analyzer is stateless and a single instance can be reused by the search application instead of instantiating an Analyzer every time I need it?

I'm currently using the EnglishAnalyzer:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzers are not stateless but the reuse of an instance is intended.

Analysers are mainly the factory class for TokenStreams and in particular the EnglishAnalyzer is thread-safe. Solr loads his analysers for each SolrCore only once. So the solr-folk have trust in thread-safety of their analysers.

From the JavaDoc of [tokenStream-Method](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html#tokenStream%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader%29):

> Subsequent calls to this method will reuse the previously stored components after resetting them...

Be aware that Analysers implements "Closeable". You can not call 
[tokenStream-Method](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html#tokenStream%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader%29) after the close-Method was called.

P.S. [lucene good practice and thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878448/lucene-good-practice-and-thread-safety)

P.P.S [QueryParser are not threadsafe](https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Is_the_QueryParser_thread-safe.3F)

Comment: Actually, I am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation: close() call missing, when accessing analyzer from two threads simultaneously while following the prescribed TokenStream workflow. This seems to suggest that the analyzers are not thread safe.

Comment: As @SumitJain mentions, they operate on a stateful reference to a token stream. 
Documentation from tokenStream():
Subsequent calls to this method will reuse the previously stored components after resetting them through {@link TokenStreamComponents#setReader(Reader)}.

Which is to say it is NOT thread safe, since a reset before a token stream is done reading is probably going to cause issues. It is reusable, which is different than thread safe.

Comment: @TylerHoppe I've been also experiencing concurrency issues with Analyzer classes. Is there any way to get around this? Syncrhonization or some other mechanisms? Also, which would be a nice way to prove the concurrency issues (TokenStream contract violation) within a unitary test?